# DataGridView.BeginEdit() fails because DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl is disposed

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, objectdisposedexception

In the code below, I simply try to do a `BeginEdit(False)` in a DataGridView. Occasionally, this fails with:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException
  HResult=0x80131622
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'DataGridViewTextBoxEditingControl'.
  Source=System.Windows.Forms
  StackTrace:
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
(...)
```

I've ensured that the cell is the *current* cell, that is is *selected*... what else can I do? With the If that I added in a vain attempt to get around the issue, I see, by debugging, that the EditingControl is `Nothing` at that point, so the code below even fails on `.EditingControl.CreateControl()` (Object not instantiated).

It can be replicated easily: edit a line, then do Escape. Escape has the `DataGridView` delete the line, resulting in the `EditingControl` becoming `Nothing`. Any further attempt to do a `BeginEdit` will result in the above error.

How can an `EditingControl` be instantiated ad associated to a cell?

A summary of the code is:

```
    dgv.Focus()
    dgv.CurrentCell = dgv.Rows(intRowNr).Cells(intColumnNr)
    dgv.CurrentRow.Cells(intColumnNr).Selected = True
    dgv.Refresh()

    If dgv.EditingControl = Nothing OrElse dgv.EditingControl.IsDisposed Then
      ' Everything here in the If is a vain attempt to circumvent the problem.
      dgv.EditingControl.CreateControl() ' Fails because the EditingControl is sometimes Nothing
      dgv.CurrentCell.InitializeEditingControl(intRow, dgv.Rows(intRow).Cells(0).Value, dgv.DefaultCellStyle)
    End If

    dgv.BeginEdit(False) ' If the If above is not there,
    ' this occasionally fails with the error above.
```

Comment: How about telling us where/when/how this code fragment is executed?  Without a context of the DGV's state, this question amounts to "Why does this random code fail?".

Comment: Difficult to add the whole code as it would quickly add hundred of lines of code and events. But by further debugging, I could rephrase the question into something much more specific. An alternative is to use SendKeys("{F2}"), but that's less clean.